# Счетчик времени с похожей функциональностью?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день. Не мог бы кто-нибудь подсказать счетчик времени (бесплатный) с перелистыванием цифр (чтобы они листались как в блокноте). Вот на этой страничке видно о чем идет речь .
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1982720/oknasdk_LP.jpg
Я так понимаю, что перелистывание должно быть реализовано через css3 transform или на canvas

Comment: >> Я так понимаю, что перелистывание должно быть реализовано через css3 transform или на canvas

Не обязательно. Делается спрайт со всеми цифрами и бекграундами в разных положениях, а потом меняется background-position

Comment: Можно было бы сделать таким образом, как вы написали, но для этого художник psd макета должен сам нарисовать части анимации. А вот если она отсутствует - это проблема. Кстати есть ли готовый скрипт счетчика под анимацию спрайта, тоже интересно?
Ну и также хотелось бы увидеть скрипт, использующий возможности js.

Comment: http://www.designrazzi.com/2013/jquery-countdown-timer-scripts/

ну почему вы избегаете гугл..

Comment: Я находила подобные ссылки. Попробуйте скачать хоть из ваших таймеров - они все платные.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте, вот эти варианты:

- http://flipclockjs.com/
- https://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/

Comment: Выглядит потрясающе. Вы не знаете - туда можно прикрепить вместо цифр картинки?